# How to send verification code via SMS. But prevent users enter phone numbers in ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I using Microsoft ADB2C for authentication. And turn on MFA via SMS.
I have a problem with the step that confirms the code.

[confirm code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGqmB.png)

In the image above. The step confirms code always needs the user to input the phone number.
So, How can I modify this step like this?

[confirm code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgdL0.png)

This step runs when I set up the Authentication method of the user by manual.
But I need automation when users sign up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you read the attribute where the phone number is stored before calling the MFA orchestration step. The phone number entry only appears if the phone number claim is null.

You will see in the AAD B2C SocialLocalAndMFA starter pack we read the strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber using AAD-UserReasUsingObjectId technical profile prior to the phonefactor mfa step.

You need to read the attribute where the phone number is written to at sign up.

Comment: Tks bro. I get it.
I have some mistakes in the verify step.